# Flask redirect after ajax request success

Tags: redirect, flask

I develop a mapping app, the front-end is created with Flask. When searching the external backend (create with the django framework) with ajax requests. I would like ***redirect the url after return from the ajax response*** (if success or not). But, I don't know the best way for this !

```
submitHandler: function () {
        /********* GET USER TOKEN WITH AJAX REQUEST**********/
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "url for get token",
            data: {
                username: $('#email-log').val(),
                password: $('#password-log').val()

            },
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.d == true) {
                    localStorage["username"] = $('#username-log').val();
                    localStorage["user_token"] = response['token'];
                    window.location = "{{url_for('maps')}}";
                }
            },
        });
    },
```

Where do I do this redirection?
In **ajax request**, in the **form action = ""**, using **url_for()** somewhere ?

I'm lost in all these methods

Comment: You cannot use **url_for** in javacript. do you need to send variables too? or just only redirect?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to redirect after Ajax success you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
        // do what you want,
        success: function(){
           window.location.href = "/url/for/route/"     //redirect url
           // or
           window.location.replace("url/for/route")
        }
    });
```

Comment: I try, but doesn't work :
           window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/maps";
           window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:5000/maps");

Comment: Change it to this: window.location.href = "/maps"; did it work?

Comment: This login form is in bootstrap modal window, maybe the cause of this failure ?

Comment: Do you really have to use ajax? Why don't you use a simpe login form.